# Drag progress bar forward and backward

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a div that acts like a progress bar, moving and displaying the status of a current song that is being played.  How can I drag that "progress bar" forward and backward to allow a person top seek through a song?

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to just use the [JQuery UI Slider](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider) if you don't mind adding JQuery to your app.

Comment: I am using the slider and want to automate the position of the handle to move the width of the div that it positioned on.  How can I do this?

The div moves because through a java-script code that stating the progress of the playing song.